# Expo push token is not being created in android standalone app

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am tryin to solve that issue long time and nothing worked, ExpopushToken is not being created in android standlone app while it's working as expected in ios. I followed the documentaions literally and created everything needed with unrestricted google cloud platform key the key was not created automatically and I did create one
The token is going to my server where should I save users data as an empty string from android

code are taken exactly from documentations, google-services file are added exactly as mentioned in the main root and uploaded app credentials to server

```
const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
    let token;
    if (Constants.isDevice) {
      const { status: existingStatus } =
        await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
        alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
        return;
      }
      token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
    } else {
      alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
    }

    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
        name: "default",
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
      });
    }

    return token;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((token) =>
      setExpoPushToken(token)
    );

    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
        setNotification(notification);
      });

    responseListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
        console.log(response, "response");
      });


    return () => {
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
        notificationListener.current
      );
      Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
    };
  }, []);
```

and in app.json

```
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-notifications",
    {
      "icon": "./assets/mainLogo.png",
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "sounds": [
        "./assets/notificationsound.wav",
        "./assets/notificationsoundothers.wav"
      ]
    }
  ],
  ["expo-image-picker"],
  ["expo-camera"]
],
"updates": {
  "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
"assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
"notification": {
  "icon": "./assets/logo2.png",
  "color": "#e8e8e8",
  "iosDisplayInForeground": true,
  "androidMode": "collapse",
  "androidCollapsedTitle": "New Notification"
},
```

Environment

> Expo CLI 4.12.0 environment info: System: OS: Windows 10 10.0.22000
> Binaries: Node: 14.16.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE npm:
> 6.14.12 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD SDKs: Android SDK: API Levels: 26, 28, 29, 30 Build Tools: 29.0.2, 30.0.3 System Images:
> android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play
> Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom IDEs: Android
> Studio: Version 4.1.0.0 AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119 npmPackages: expo:
> ~43.0.2 => 43.0.3 react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 react-dom: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
> react-native: 0.64.3 => 0.64.3 react-native-web: 0.17.1 => 0.17.1 Expo
> Workflow: managed

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the issue for whom may pass here
In Expo docs it's mentioned that you have to check the api key downloaded with google-services.json file and make sure it's the same yours.... it will not be yours and if you change to your api key it will not work. keep it as it is downloaded and it will work

I figured this after spending 5 days in searching with no results